# ¿Como resuelvo esta consigna en java?

Tags: java, clase, uml

Bueno pues necesito ayuda con esta consigna de un problema a resolver en java, me dan un diagrama de clase uml y tengo que implementarlo en java, pero no comprendo por que al parecer pide realizar dos clases para testear? pero como hago eso si solo una es la que corre? Tambien en una de esas clases test nos pide que hagamos un menu de opciones en la que el usuario pueda realizar distintas cosas, pero en la opcion "A" dice textualmente "Cargar los datos de los boxeadores. El arreglo será dimensionado con un valor
ingresado por el usuario, ya que la cantidad de participantes del campeonato es
determinada por el organizador del campeonato.", esto no tiene sentido para mi, me esta diciendo que la dimension osea tamaño de el array de los datos de los boxeadores la va a determinar el usuario pero despues me dice que la cantidad de participantes la determina el organizador, entonces quien es el que determina la cantidad de elementos de el array?.
Procedo a dejarles el problema con el uml abajo y despues el codigo que hice.

"*Se ha organizado un campeonato de boxeo para las categorias Pesado (P) -hombres de
más de 94 kg-, Crucero (C)-hombres entre 79 y 94 kg; y Semipesado (S) hombres menos
de 79 kg. Los datos de los boxeadores están almacenados en un arreglo de Boxeadores.
Se solicita implementar la clase Boxeador especificada en el diagrama UML y un
programa que permita probar la clase Boxeador con la definición de los atributos y la
implementación de los siguientes métodos: los dos constructores, una operación
observadora a elección, el método toString, una operación modificadora a elección y las
operaciones propias del tipo. Como indicamos anteriormente la categoria depende del
peso del boxeador, cuando se modifique el peso se debe modificar la Categoría
invocando el método setCategoría (un método privado a la clase).
El IMC (Indice de Masa Corporal) se obtiene a partir de la siguiente fórmula IMC = peso /
(estatura 2 ). Estadísticamente suele ganar el boxeador con mayor IMC. El método
puedeGanarle() devuelve verdadero o falso al comparar los IMC de dos boxeadores.
Implementar además una clase TestBoxeador que a través de un menú de opciones
permita:
a) Cargar los datos de los boxeadores. El arreglo será dimensionado con un valor
ingresado por el usuario, ya que la cantidad de participantes del campeonato es
determinada por el organizador del campeonato.
b) Mostrar por pantalla los datos de todos los boxeadores que pertenecen a una categoría
dada.
c) Dado un boxeador determinar a que otros boxeadores de la misma categoría puede
ganarle.*"

[image: Diagrama UML de la clase boxeador antes mencionado]

Dejo a continuacion el codigo de la clase Boxeador implementada en java.

```
package programaboxeadorestp5;

public class Boxeador {
    
    private String apellido;
    private double estatura;
    private int peso;
    private char categoria;
    
    
    public Boxeador(String apellido, double estatura, int peso){
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.estatura = estatura;
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    
    //GETTERS
    public String get_apellido(){
        return apellido;
    }
    
    public double get_estatura(){
        return estatura;
    }
    
    public int get_peso(){
        return peso;
    }
    
    public char get_categoria(){
        return categoria;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Apellido: " + apellido + "\nEstatura: " + estatura + "\nPeso: " + peso + "\nCategoria: " + categoria;
    }
    
    //SETTERS
    public void set_apellido(String apellido){
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    
    public void set_estatura(double estatura){
        this.estatura = estatura;
    }
    
    public void set_peso(int peso){
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    
    private void set_categoria(char categoria){
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
    
    //PRopios
    
    private double obtenerIMC(){
        double imc = peso * (estatura * estatura);
        return imc;
    }
    
    public boolean puedeGanarle(Boxeador boxead){
        if (this.obtenerIMC() > boxead.obtenerIMC()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}

Y esto es lo que tengo de la clase test:

package programaboxeadorestp5;
import utiles.TecladoIn;

public class Test_Boxeador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char respuesta;
        
        System.out.println("Menu de opciones");
        System.out.println("a) Cargar datos de boxeadores");
        System.out.println("b) Mostrar datos de boxeadores de una categoria");
        System.out.println("c) Comparar el IMC de dos boxeadores para ver quien es mas probable que gane");
        
        respuesta = TecladoIn.readLineNonwhiteChar();
        
        switch (respuesta){
            case 'a':
                
        }
                
                    
    }
    
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar por que es urgente, espero que no moleste un mensaje tan largo y gracias si leiste todo, gracias de antemano a quienes puedan ayudarme.
PD: Soy nuevo en stack overflow, perdonen si hice algun error :p

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema. Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola, creo que no leiste toda mi publicacion, contexto? es un problema que me dieron en una clase y tengo que resolverlo y no se como, que intente? lo que puse ahi, mi codigo, cual es el problema puntual? hay varios, como frases sin sentido en la consigna y cosas que no quedan claras, te digo esto desde el mayor respeto para que no te lo tomes a mal. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Lei absolutamente todo. Hay una enunciado completo... hay varias preguntas confusas, como lo de la clase de test o problemas de interpretacion del ejercicio (que solo lo pueden resolver quien te dio el ejercicio). Tu codigo, no nos dice donde tiene el problema ni que problema tiene. Tu publicacion esta completa, pero no queda claro que buscas como solucion. Tene en cuenta que aca se resuelven problemas puntuales que tengas con tu codigo.

Comment: voto por cerrarla hasta que @Danielk edite la publicación y agregue mas contexto.

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)